# dsx-desktop Notebooks and Data don't show up

Tags: dsx-desktop

I have installed dsx and created a Notebook. When I go to my Notebooks it's blank.

But, if I try to create a new Notebook with the same name it states that it already exist?

/Mike

Comment: Please can you upload a snippet of the last few lines of your log file (%appdata%\ibm-dsx-desktop\Logs) Do you see any of these errors in the log file:
[info] runCommand: \ibm-dsx-desktop\Notebooks\myNotebooks/o:-d /a:-d | find "/"
[error] exec error: Error: stdout maxBuffer exceeded OR [info] runCommand: dir \ibm-dsx-desktop\Notebooks\myNotebooks\assets\/o:-d /a:-d | find "/" If so, then, these issues will be addressed in the next version of DSX Desktop (v1.01.01)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I works with the latest version of DSX-local.

Thanks!